# Remove/ delete or hide column in spotfire

Tags: ironpython, tibco, spotfire

How to remove/delete or hide column using iron script in spotfire ?

For adding a column i have done as follows:

`

```
curDT = Document.ActiveDataTableReference
cols = curDT.Columns
# targetCol = Document.Properties["myColumnSelection"]

#Create a new column that counts the comma delimiter
myExpression = '1+len(RXReplace([Cx],"([A-Za-z0-9]+)","","g"))'
myNewColName = cols.CreateUniqueName("NumElements")
cols.AddCalculatedColumn(myNewColName, myExpression)
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if it can still be helpful:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
contentTable = myTableVisualization.As[VisualContent]()
if contentTable.TableColumns.Contains(myData.Columns["MyColumn"]):
        contentTable.TableColumns.Remove(myData.Columns["MyColumn"])
```

Comment: Is it possible to actually delete the column from the data table using a similar script?

Comment: How to hide a column?

Answer (score 2):

Remove a column by

cols.Remove("NameOfColumnToRemove")