# Update/Remove Calculated Column using IronPython

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

I'm using Spotfire and would like to know if there's a way of updating or removing a calculated column using IronPython code.

Ex:
Let's pretend I have a table with: 
`| Column 1 | Column 2| Column 3 | Calculated Column |`

So, every time I run a specific script, I want it to change the values of the *calculated Column*.

PS: I already have the below code to create the column if needed. So, if there is at least a way of deleting the column, it would also work for me.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import CalculatedColumn

newColName = "MY_CALCULATED_COLUMN"
newColExpr = "TRIM([myTableCol])"
Document.Data.Tables["MY_TABLE"].Columns.AddCalculatedColumn(newColName,newColExpr).As[CalculatedColumn]()
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but I'm curious why the solution over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108946/remove-delete-or-hide-column-in-spotfire didn't work for you?

Comment: I've tested this one. Unfortunately, it's only removing the column from the table visualisation, not from the data table itself.

Comment: gotcha, looking at it a second time I see what you mean :) lemme poke around a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the following code will work for you:

```
newColName = "col"
Document.Data.Tables["Data Table"].Columns.Remove(newColName)
```

(you don't need to import any classes for this one)

you can find additional info in the [API documentation](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/api/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Spotfire_Dxp_Data_DataColumnCollection.htm).

Comment: That's PERFECT @niko! Simple and effective.